# Can Firebase Test Lab run Monkeyrunner tests?

Tags: android, libgdx, monkeyrunner, firebase-test-lab

I'm not really sure if this is the correct stack exchange site to ask on, but I can't find anything via google, SO search or on the firebase or android developer sites.

I want to make use of the free spark tier of Firebase Test Lab to run MonkeyRunner tests, but I can't see any way of doing that, or if it's even possible.

I apologise if this is out of context.

I need to do Monkeyrunner tests as my project is a LibGDX project which has no Android classes in it, so I can't benefit from the normal instrumentation tests.

Comment: Screenshots that you take with Screenshotter on Test Lab will get pulled into the test results in a storage bucket after the test.  You can access that bucket with the "View Source Files" button at the top of the test results.

Comment: But I can't use ScreenShotter because in UIAutomator, we don't have an Activity. or at least, I can't find a way to get it.

Comment: Could you take your additional questions to a different issue here on SO?  You've packed too much into this one question - it's difficult to follow.  Your first question was about monkeyrunner, which got answered.  Your other questions are about different topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not currently.  Monkeyrunner is a python program that directs the emulator or device after the APK is deployed to it.  Test Lab doesn't have a way to also deploy and execute a python program that runs in this fashion.  That complicates things greatly.  If you would like to submit this as a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), we would love the details of your app and why you're trying to do with it.

Comment: Hi, Doug, thanks for replying. Basically I am writing a game on Android using a Library/Framework called LibGDX. It's basically written in pure Java, using LWJGL which sits inside a single Activity. Because of that, there are no real Android UI classes, with which to control the UI tests. To be honest, the main thing I want at the moment, is just the ability to take screenshots on many devices, as I'm only a solo dev at the moment, and my funds don't stretch to me trying my game on the latest devices, or at least not many of them (only what I can borrow from friends)

Comment: p.s. feature requested

Comment: Sorry to turn this into a correspondence, but Doug, I found SnapShotter in the TestLab docs and this looks great, but when I try and use it in my UIAutomator tests, it needs an Activity, when I only have a Context. Do you know if there is anyway to get an Activity from something like the launcher intent, or am I doomed to not be able to use this either :(

Comment: Maybe just ask separate question, since that's unrelated to this one?

Comment: @RussWheeler can you describe what are you doing in your tests, sending events and taking screenshots, IIUC?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I've updated my original post to give some more info. Or were you looking for actual code of what I'm trying?